# "Main Class Not Found" error when running jar file through Windows Explorer

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

This question seems to have been asked on SO several times, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.
When I `Compile and Build` a java jar file through Netbeans, I get the following error: **"Could not find main class. Program will exit"**.
So far, I have been using a .bat file to run it from command-line, through `java -jar <jar name>` but that is an inconvenience, especially when distributing the jar file to other users.
I have reinstalled my JDK and JRE, added everything to PATH and in short, tried everything I could.
Any solutions please?

### **EDIT - Add MANIFEST.MF Contents**

As requested by @Psychrom, here is my `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_45-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: main
```

To be clear, this is the default `MANIFEST.MF` being generated by Netbeans. Haven't meddled with any special settings at all.

Comment: Are you doing a full clean/rebuild and then using the jar created in the dist folder?

Comment: Yes, precisely that.
The jar runs fine from within Netbeans, through the **Run Main Project** button, but doesn't when I try from the `dist` folder.

Comment: Would you mind posting your Manifest file?

Also, would you verify that at least one of your class files contains a main method? 

I've run into this problem twice myself, and each time it's been because of a simple mismatch.

Comment: @Psychrom updated the question. Please check.
Also, I have only one class file, called `main`.

Comment: Your Main-Class is incorrect.

It should be 

packagename.CLASSNAME

package1.SOMECLASS


This tells it to look in the package the correct class. Yours simply says the class name, whereas it does not tell you what package to look in, or vice versa.

Comment: In Netbeans, there is the option of using the `Default Package` when you create a new class. So I am using that. In that option.
And just for the record, I tried making a separate package and placing my file there, still no use.

Comment: Check this out http://imgur.com/7PfoNmA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85248/discussion-between-psychrom-and-kanishka-ganguly).

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve an runnable jar would be to ensure you include a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in your jar with the key "Main-Class:" defined inside the MANIFEST.MF file.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to netbeans, but I might have a solution.

Right click on your project name in the sidebar (If the sidebar isn't there go to Window on the toolbar and hit Projects) > Properties > Run > Main Class text area and either type it in or hit browse and select your main class.

A suggestion: Also in properties, > Packaging > Compress JAR File if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens when there is a difference between your jre and jdk. This will explain the problem with the solution. 
http://benohead.com/java-find-main-class-program-will-exit/#comment-471275